# Java JTable JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am having trouble with inserting a JButton in a JTable.
I am trying to have a button that when it will be click, a new panel qui comeup with more information about the selected data.

Here is my code for the button:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(button), 
                            "Button clicked for row "+rowIndex);
                }
            });
            return button;
        case 1: return card.getType().toString();
        case 2: return card.getAccNb();
        case 3: return card.getCardNumber();
        case 4: return card.getMoneyAvailable();
        }
    }
```

And here is what I get as an output in the table:
[image]

If you need more info, please tell me, I am really stuck here :S

Comment: I don't see how it is a duplicate as I am giving my code and an image of the issue and have no solution for it so far

Comment: I would highly recommend having a look at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer), [Using Other Editors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Comment: Does the duplicate show buttons in `JTable`, which can interacted with?  Explain to me how it's not a duplicate?  You need to understand that your attempt is the wrong approach. The `TableModel` should never carry components, it should carry data. You then use renderers to display the data in the format you want (ie a button) and an editor to allow the user to interact with it

Comment: *"I am trying to have a button that when it will be click, a new panel qui comeup with more information about the selected data"* - Two thoughts on that issue.  1- You could have a single button (not on the table), which when the row selection changes is enabled, and allows the user to activate it and perform the required action or 2- Simply allow the user to double click the row.  It's a personal thing, but I dislike buttons in tables

Comment: I went through a dozen other similar questions, but since they seem to be all answered by camickr, they all link to [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) which is also linked into the duplicate